# bootstrap typeahead ugly completion

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using bootstrap(2.3.2 version) typeahead completion in my rails project with simple_form but not only does it suggest the completion set but it also writes the first matched string in the field, making it ugly. what is the solution? it there any option to disable it?

[image: typeahead]

**UPDATE1:** by the way, to enable this completion feature, I included an external js file ( I mean it was not implemented in bootstrap) and as it is suggested in the Q&As, I used [this](https://github.com/jharding/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css/blob/master/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css) css file to keep the UI beautiful.

Comment: What version of bootstrap?

Comment: Looks like a css issue to me, if you styled the text in the input to match the text that's being displayed behind it (or vice versa) it wouldn't look like that.

Comment: I think there is some css conflict, did you check it?